# Error occurred during build - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

This are the details of the error:

```
Errors occurred during the build .
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Vivid'
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'appcompat_v7'
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: give us the logcat readout